# How to simulate onblur event with Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am automating login scenario of an application.

The execution steps are as below:

1. Select the Country
2. Enter the Username
3. Enter the Password
4. Click on Login Button.

Actually after entered the username, application validates the country and username in database exists or not.

When tried to automate through robot framework, this validation is not called and so unable to login (actually login button is clicked through script, but no error message or no response user is in same page).

When i verified exact scenario it calling the validation, comes to know that 
validation is called on `onblur` of the usename element `onblur="getlocation()"`.

I tried to simulate this by give tabout from username field through script as 
`Press Key    ${element path}    \\9` but it is not working always out of 10 run only 3 or 4 times it working.

Is there any way we can do 'blur` action on the element in robot framework

Comment: Not really answering your question, but have you tried to focus the onblur element? Using Mouse Over, for example.

Comment: I didn't try using mouse over but I tried focus to element , enter the value and then tab out from element

Comment: I tried to use `mouse over`, i got webdriver exception. when i googled it, i got the information that the issue exist with firefox marrionette for Mouse events, please check [issue link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285)

Comment: Have you tried to click another (possibly dummy/hidden) element on page?

Comment: `click element` is working but not `double click element` or `mouse over` and other mouse elements. I tried with other elements also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Selenium2Library for robot, there is a special keyword for that:

```
Simulate  <element>  <event>
```

In my keyword definition it looks like this:

```
I Enter The New Password
  [Arguments]   ${text}
  Input Text   ${INPUT_ELEMENT_PASSWORD}   ${text}
  Simulate  ${INPUT_ELEMENT_PASSWORD}  blur
```

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Simulate

I hope that helps, it took us a while to figure out what was missing in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Just to save few minutes of googling.

```
Simulate
```

is deprecated. Use

```
Simulate Event
```

instead